# Как сделать отступ от зафиксированного header и footer?

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка:

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

header {
 top: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin:0px auto;
 position: fixed;
   z-index: 999;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   background: #fff;
}

#pageContent {
 margin: 70px 0px;
 z-index: 998;
 background: yellow;
}

footer {
 bottom: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 position: fixed;
   z-index: 999;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>header</header>
  <section id="pageContent">
      content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>
  </section>

  <footer>footer</footer>

</body>
```

и получается что вверху страницы есть отступ, а внизу его не видно(он заметен только когда долистать страницу вниз): 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так у вашего хедера высота 50px, а у секции margin 70px. В результате и пробел!

Comment: @DmitriiSedov все верно, мне этот "пробел" и нужен. только нужно чтобы изначально при загрузки страницы он был виден как под `header` так и над `footer`. То есть что-то типа когда хеадер и футер высотой 50px, потом после хеадер отступаем 50px и перед футер также 50px а остальная вся высота для `pageContent `

Answer (score 2):

Без использования js может помочь такой подход. Так как хедер и футер имеют фиксированную позицию, то относительно них не получится позиционировать, так как они не зависят от контента внутри и лежат поверх всего, имея определённую позицию на экране. Но для решения Вашей задачи воспользуйтесь кодом ниже (добавлено у page-content height: `calc(100vh - 140px); overflow-y: auto;`.

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

header {
 top: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin:0px auto;
 position: fixed;
   z-index: 999;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   background: #fff;
}

#pageContent {
 margin: 70px 0px;
 z-index: 998;
 background: yellow;
  height: calc(100vh - 140px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
 bottom: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 position: fixed;
   z-index: 999;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>header</header>
  <section id="pageContent">
      content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>
  </section>

  <footer>footer</footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать таким образом с помощью псевдоэлемента `:after`:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
}

header:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

#pageContent {
  margin: 70px 0px;
  z-index: 998;
  background: yellow;
}

footer {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
}

footer:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>header</header>
  <section id="pageContent">
    content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>    content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>    content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>    content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>    content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>    content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br> content<br>
  </section>

  <footer>footer</footer>

</body>
```